# Is there any mechanism for revoking flag privileges?

Tags: feature-request, flags, flag-weight

Is there a mechanism that counts the total number of flags raised by each user, and calculates the percentage of those flags that get rejected? If not, may we have one?

If the rejection number is too high — say, ten flags rejected in a day, 25 rejected in a week or 50 rejected in a month — the system should revoke the user's ability to cast more flags for a specific, pre-determined period of time, or even forever.

This would help moderators because they wouldn't have to review as many spammy flags — in other words, flags that are themselves spam, not to be confused with flags reporting spam posts — or as many instances of users getting flagged for no good reason.

Comment: There is flag weight--and that ranks your flags in the queue (I think)

Comment: Why are you worried about this?

Comment: @Dennis Why should i not..just got something like this in mind..so asked here,to get know more clear on this.

Comment: @TimManishEarth okay..sorry..i had no info like "flag weight make flag in queue" - that's a good feature.

Comment: @Frankenstein: You didn't ask how the system currently works (which, as a curious person, I would have understood), you made a feature request.

Comment: I tried to edit your post for spelling and grammar, but the original version was incredibly difficult for me to read. If I got something wrong, please let me know.

Comment: @Dennis: your first comment is pretty ironic given the whining on meta over flag weight which has now hidden it. Now people are worrying about people who have too many denied flags because they can't see it!

Comment: Yeah the Edit conveys the right meaning as what I intended, Thanks :)

Comment: @RobertColumbia that’s a completely different question...

Comment: @Stormblessed but it answers the question - yes, there is a means for revoking flag privileges, and here is what it used to be and what it is today.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allowing moderators to remove flag bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337007/allowing-moderators-to-remove-flag-bans) - A bit of the *math* is there, and here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315507/immediately-rebanned-after-flag-ban-was-lifted-should-i-wait-to-flag-again

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This already happens, sort of.

Long story short; we used to have something called flag weight. Firstly, it was a super-secret feature, then SE put it on everyone's profiles. Then every invalid flag ever was disputed here on meta. Then they decided to show a count of helpful flags instead.

As I understand it, flag weight still exists, you just can't see it.

One of the features of flag weight is that when your flag weight hits zero, your flags are ignored. Forever. Flags are shown to moderators based on a secret formula that involves flag weight, I think - so accurate flaggers flags come out top.

Every valid flag increases your flag weight, every invalid flag decreases it, so how "important" your flag is gets altered over time to correct for your accuracy.

Comment: ............yup

Comment: thanks for the answer..i had no info like "flag weight make flag in queue" - that's a good feature.

Comment: "Forever" is a little dramatic. The rule used to be that you could get out of zero flag weight if you and another user both flagged the same post and the other person's flag was marked helpful. As far as I know, that hasn't changed.