# Flag ban banner showing false ban lift day

Tags: support, notification-bar, flag-ban

Not that I am complaining about being allowed to flag posts, but I got really scared when I saw this banner in my flag history after I had randomly tried to flag a post and succeeded and assumed that it is [all behind me now](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtsTMJoXsTc).

> [image]

Comment: Do take a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/369802. Flag bans look if at least 10 of your flags were handled in the past 7 days. If (more than) 25 percent of those flags end up declined, you enter a flag ban. Could it be that today marked the day where you had only 9 handled flags for the past 7 days, so you could flag 1 post again?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell oh wait while writing this question I had assumed that I can flag. But turns out I cannot. So this seems to be a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315507/immediately-rebanned-after-flag-ban-was-lifted-should-i-wait-to-flag-again?rq=1

Comment: Well, having an extra helpful flag won't hurt ;) Try and get one tomorrow too, it'll help get out of the >=25% declined in the past 7 days faster :)

Comment: I dont follow.. how do I get one more tomorrow and today even, while I cannot raise one on AD? are you talking about this site? Aren't flag counts site specific?

Comment: You can flag posts on that site again tomorrow, apparently. Try and flag something that'll be marked helpful, and it will help to decrease the percentage of declined flags you've had over the past 7 days there. That way, you might get out of your flag ban a little sooner than just waiting until 7 days after your last declined flag :)