# Allow sorting flags by handling time instead of flagging time on the flag history/summary page

Tags: feature-request, flags, sorting, flag-history

Sometimes, it happens that my helpful flag counter ends up increasing, but when I check my recent flags, none of them have been dismissed yet. In this case, what has likely happened is that one of my much older flags has finally been handled, but there's no easy way to check which one that was without going through my entire flag list and trying to recall which one was unhandled the last time I checked.

When mousing over a flag's outcome in the flag history page, there's a tooltip that tells me when a flag was handled, so at least it's possible to see that. However, that's hard to use, since you can only view one at a time, and you can't see it *at all* from a mobile device (since tooltips are unsupported there). It's really painful when trying to see in which order one's flags were handled.

This is also useful to users who were banned from flagging, so that they can easily see why they were banned, the proportion of their overall flags handled in the last seven days that were declined, and [whether or not they will be re-banned even if their next flag is marked helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315508/377214).

Can there please be a way to sort one's flags in the order they were *dismissed with an outcome*, not just in the order they were cast?

Comment: I filed an issue on SOX back in September for this, but direct support would be better. https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues/499