# Allow filtering of flags by sub-type in addition to their status

Tags: feature-request, flags, flag-history

The table on *Your flagging history* at the moment can be filtered down on the flag-type (post, comment, spam, rude/abusive flags) and within each type on its status (waiting for review, helpful, declined, disputed, aged away, retracted; availability depending on whether a flag in that category exists).

[image: Flagging history screenshot]

I have quite a few flags (>10,000 helpful on Stack Overflow) and would like to be able to filter on my custom flags. Whether that filter is a sub-filter of the flag status or another category altogether doesn't matter much. Currently, I'd need to go through roughly 75 pages of helpful post flags to see those.

Can the option be added to allow filtering on flag subtype, i.e. Not An Answer, Very Low Quality or Custom for answers? Possibly the same for comments (No longer Needed, unfriendly, harassment, custom).

Comment: I also want this. Before I became a mod if I wanted to see what a mod replied to my custom flag I had to scroll tens of pages before I could see the flag from last week.

Comment: @Dharman I did file a related request, to allow users to sort their flags in the order handled rather than cast: [Allow sorting flags by handling time instead of flagging time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347234/allow-sorting-flags-by-handling-time-instead-of-flagging-time)