# Where can I see the number of flags that were marked as helpful over the past 7 days?

Tags: support, flag-history, flag-ban

When getting a flag ban, one can [easily](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2d66.png) see the number of flags that were declined over the past 7 days. Where can I see the number of flags that were marked as helpful over the past 7 days?

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure there's no easy way. You can see when a flag was handled by hovering over "helpful" but there's no guarantee that your flags were handled in the order you raised them.

Comment: Related: [Allow sorting flags by handling time instead of flagging time on the flag history/summary page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347234/allow-sorting-flags-by-handling-time-instead-of-flagging-time-on-the-flag-histor)