# Can having many flags marked as helpful after a flag ban undo a flag ban?

Tags: support, flags, flag-ban

Assume some raised 40 flags. The first 3 flags got declined the first day, causing a 7-day flag ban. In the next 4 days, no other flags are declined, and several flags are marked as helpful. Can this cause the flag ban to be canceled?

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks, the answer says that the hellban doesn't exist anymore. Is the example in my question a hellban? I thought the ban would disappear in 7 days. I'm not sure of the definition of a flag hellban. The tag description for hellban (https://meta.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/4126) is confusing: it just seems to try to be funny rather than useful.

Comment: The answer explains the algorithm. You can use it to determine what will happen. hellbanning is what happened before all of that, it's no longer relevant.

Comment: @Joachim Their question was tagged as status-completed (9 years ago). So it should be done.

Comment: Also, @FranckDernoncourt, see [this comment by Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban#comment588943_175405): "*There's an even odder edge-case possible for 3 declined flags followed by 7 good ones. Our observations so far indicate that these would be fairly rare though.*"

Comment: I am confused by the other page. It's talking about some hellban and have very long comment threads (that could be removed at any time). It's hard to infer from it whether getting flags marked as helpful may cause the 7-day flag ban to be canceled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Immediately rebanned after flag ban was lifted; should I wait to flag again?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315507/immediately-rebanned-after-flag-ban-was-lifted-should-i-wait-to-flag-again) - per the answer there, *it's calculated on the fly whenever you attempt to flag a post*.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog thanks. Can  getting flags marked as helpful may cause the 7-day flag ban to be canceled? I don't see the answer anywhere.

Comment: See the edited version of my comment where I quote the part of the answer that addresses your question, and the entire paragraph it's quoted from.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog thanks, I see, so the 7-day flag can be lifted if the user clicks on "flag" and some of their flags got marked  as helpful in the recent past?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how it works.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog got it, thanks!

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I believe that's incorrect. My flag can got lifted even though I didn't click on "flag". I think this shows the usefulness of having a question focusing on the conditions when a flag ban gets cancelled before it expires.

Comment: It's still the same. Whether or not you're flag-banned is calculated on the fly at any moment. The shown time as to when you'll be un-banned is based on the assumption that no other flags of yours are handled after it's imposed, which, as you point out, isn't necessarily true. (Also, note that my answer was posted before the flag history page indicated flag bans.)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog at any moment != when the user clicks on "flag".

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect that.