# Allowing moderators to remove flag bans

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools, flag-ban

Recently, I had a situation at Travel.SE, where I raised flags in good faith misunderstanding the purpose. Out of 7 declined flags in the past 7 days, 3 were my mistake, 3 were in good faith and 1 was later actioned.

Read more about it here:

- [7 day overkill flag ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336967/7-day-overkill-flag-ban)

Quoting a moderator in [Travel.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52335790#52335790):

> I think a 7-day ban is definitely an overkill.
> I agree with automated silencing bans after too many rejected flags,
> but the duration should be shorter

The mods have no way to remove such bans and have to contact a CM, when I'm sure the CM has much better things to do. Can we allow mods to remove automatic flag bans?

Comment: Is it really worth it? I mean, it's just a week where you can't flag. You can still ask and answer questions, post comments, there's no black mark against you. This doesn't seem like a very big deal. Am I missing something?

Comment: Who flag , it's matter. We flag with good faith not for ban.

Comment: @Shree yes, I completely understand that it is annoying and unfair, I'm just saying that it is a pretty minor thing and over in one week. Is it really worth spending dev time on this?

Comment: @terdon Technically: [If at least a quarter of 10 or more flags were declined during the past 7 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/declined-flags) > If you drop below '10 flags handled during the past 7 days' you can raise more before 7 days are up. If these are helpful, they will also help to make your percentage of declined flags for the past 7 days lower, meaning that the ban might be shorter still...

Comment: @terdon I am familiar with your good faith . Some time system sucks ....................

Comment: [Immediately rebanned after flag ban was lifted; should I wait to flag again?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315507/immediately-rebanned-after-flag-ban-was-lifted-should-i-wait-to-flag-again) you might soon need to read this question too!

Comment: [I'm moving the maths to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1396/discussion-on-question-by-daniil-allowing-moderators-to-remove-flag-bans).